# Issues with multiple If and Else If statements in command line

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

Essentially I'm working on a project in command line, and I'm trying to have multiple if statements with multiple conditions to end up with something, in this case, echo displaying something. Here's an example:

```
if %piece%==1 if %haut%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 1 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 1 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==1 if %haut%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 1 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 1 2 2
))
```

Now this works fine, displaying what's shown beside echo, and when I add a second one, it also works fine, like so:

```
if %piece%==1 if %haut%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 1 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 1 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==1 if %haut%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 1 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 1 2 2
))

if %piece%==2 if %haut%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 2 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 2 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==2 if %haut%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 2 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 2 2 2
))
```

But once I add a third one which has a different second condition, instead of haut it's pantalon, it suddenly crashes the program instead of giving the answer.

```
if %piece%==1 if %haut%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 1 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 1 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==1 if %haut%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 1 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 1 2 2
))

if %piece%==2 if %haut%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 2 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 2 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==2 if %haut%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 2 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 2 2 2
))

if %piece%==3 if %pantalon%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo pantalon 3 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo pantalon 3 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==3 if %pantalon%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo pantalon 3 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo pantalon 3 2 2
))
```

I've also tried doing it without the else if, and just having many if statements stacked, but the same problem arises. I'll add the entire code at the end just in case it's needed, but I really don't know what the issue is here and why this is being caused. If someone could help me out, it'd be really appreciated!

Here's the full code:

```
@echo off

:menu
cls
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Quelle piece vestimentaire voulez-vous?
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo -------
echo Hommes
echo -------
echo Haut (1)
echo.
echo Haut (2)
echo.
echo Pantalon (3)
echo.
echo -------
echo Femmes/Tous genres confondus
echo -------
echo Haut (4)
echo.
echo Jupe (5)
echo.
echo Pantalon (6)
echo.
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo.
set /p piece=

if %piece%==1 goto haut
if %piece%==2 goto haut
if %piece%==3 goto pantalon
if %piece%==4 goto haut
if %piece%==5 goto jupe
if %piece%==6 goto pantalon

:haut
cls
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Quelle style d'haut voulez-vous?
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Haut (1)
echo.
echo Haut (2)
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
set /p haut=

goto couleur

:pantalon
cls
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Quelle style de pantalon voulez-vous?
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Pantalon (1)
echo.
echo Pantalon (2)
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
set /p pantalon=

goto couleur

:jupe
cls
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Quelle style de jupe voulez-vous?
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Jupe (1)
echo.
echo Jupe (2)
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
set /p jupe=

goto couleur

:couleur
cls
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Quelle couleurs voulez-vous?
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Rouge et noir (1)
echo.
echo Blue et noir (2)
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo.
set /p couleur=

:export
cls

if %piece%==1 if %haut%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 1 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 1 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==1 if %haut%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 1 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 1 2 2
))

if %piece%==2 if %haut%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 2 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 2 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==2 if %haut%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 2 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 2 2 2
))

if %piece%==3 if %pantalon%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo pantalon 3 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo pantalon 3 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==3 if %pantalon%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo pantalon 3 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo pantalon 3 2 2
))

if %piece%==4 if %haut%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 4 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 4 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==4 if %haut%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 4 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 4 2 2
))

if %piece%==5 if %jupe%==1 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 4 1 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 4 1 2
)) 
if %piece%==5 if %jupe%==2 (
    if %couleur%==1 (
        echo haut 4 2 1
) else if %couleur%==2 (
        echo haut 4 2 2
))

pause>nul
goto menu
```

If there's any other information you need I'll be happy to give it!

Comment: check if `%pantalon%` is properly defined. Your description screams, it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise that you do not use `Set /P` to receive expected single digit known input, and instead use the more appropriate and built-in `choice.exe` utility. This will guarantee that the end user can only provide input from your known list.

As for your `if` / `else`, structure, I have removed some unnecessary things, because if many of the options are not `1`, they must by default, be `2`, so there's no need to ask a second `if`.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

:Menu
ClS
Set /A haut=pantalon=jupe=couleur=0
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle piece vestimentaire voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo -------
Echo Hommes
Echo -------
Echo Haut (1)
Echo(
Echo Haut (2)
Echo(
Echo Pantalon (3)
Echo(
Echo -------
Echo Femmes/Tous genres confondus
Echo -------
Echo Haut (4)
Echo(
Echo Jupe (5)
Echo(
Echo Pantalon (6)
Echo(
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 123456
Set "piece=%ERRORLEVEL%"
If %piece%==1 GoTo Haut
If %piece%==2 GoTo Haut
If %piece%==3 GoTo Pantalon
If %piece%==4 GoTo Haut
If %piece%==5 GoTo Jupe
If %piece%==6 GoTo Pantalon

:Haut
ClS
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle style d'haut voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Haut (1)
Echo(
Echo Haut (2)
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12
Set "haut=%ERRORLEVEL%"
GoTo Couleur

:Pantalon
ClS
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle style de pantalon voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Pantalon (1)
Echo(
Echo Pantalon (2)
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12
Set "pantalon=%ERRORLEVEL%"
GoTo Couleur

:Jupe
ClS
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle style de jupe voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Jupe (1)
Echo(
Echo Jupe (2)
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12
Set "jupe=%ERRORLEVEL%"
GoTo Couleur

:Couleur
ClS
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle couleurs voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Rouge et noir (1)
Echo(
Echo Blue et noir (2)
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12
Set "couleur=%ERRORLEVEL%"

:Export
ClS
If %piece%==1 (
    If %haut%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo haut 1 1 1
        ) Else (
            Echo haut 1 1 2
        )
    ) Else (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo haut 1 2 1
        ) Else (
            Echo haut 1 2 2
        )
    )
)
If %piece%==2 (
    If %haut%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo haut 2 1 1
        ) Else (
            Echo haut 2 1 2
        )
    ) Else (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo haut 2 2 1
        ) Else (
            Echo haut 2 2 2
        )
    )
)
If %piece%==3 (
    If %pantalon%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo pantalon 3 1 1
        ) Else (
            Echo pantalon 3 1 2
        )
    ) Else (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo pantalon 3 2 1
        ) Else (
            Echo pantalon 3 2 2
        )
    )
)
If %piece%==4 (
    If %haut%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo haut 4 1 1
        ) Else (
            Echo haut 4 1 2
        )
    ) Else (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo haut 4 2 1
        ) Else (
            Echo haut 4 2 2
        )
    )
)
If %piece%==5 (
    If %jupe%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo jupe 5 1 1
        ) Else (
            Echo jupe 5 1 2
        )
    ) Else (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo jupe 5 2 1
        ) Else (
            Echo jupe 5 2 2
        )
    )
)
If %piece%==6 (
    If %pantalon%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo pantalon 6 1 1
        ) Else (
            Echo pantalon 6 1 2
        )
    ) Else (
        If %couleur%==1 (
            Echo pantalon 6 2 1
        ) Else (
            Echo pantalon 6 2 2
        )
    )
)
Pause 1>NUL
GoTo Menu
```

---

Personally however, I'd perform the if section more like this:

```batch-file
If %piece%==1 If %haut%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (Echo haut 1 1 1) Else Echo haut 1 1 2
    ) Else If %couleur%==1 (Echo haut 1 2 1) Else Echo haut 1 2 2
If %piece%==2 If %haut%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (Echo haut 2 1 1) Else Echo haut 2 1 2
    ) Else If %couleur%==1 (Echo haut 2 2 1) Else Echo haut 2 2 2
If %piece%==3 If %pantalon%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (Echo pantalon 3 1 1) Else Echo pantalon 3 1 2
    ) Else If %couleur%==1 (Echo pantalon 3 2 1) Else Echo pantalon 3 2 2
If %piece%==4 If %haut%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (Echo haut 4 1 1) Else Echo haut 4 1 2
    ) Else If %couleur%==1 (Echo haut 4 2 1) Else Echo haut 4 2 2
If %piece%==5 If %jupe%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (Echo jupe 5 1 1) Else Echo jupe 5 1 2
    ) Else If %couleur%==1 (Echo jupe 5 2 1) Else Echo jupe 5 2 2
If %piece%==6 If %pantalon%==1 (
        If %couleur%==1 (Echo pantalon 6 1 1) Else Echo pantalon 6 1 2
    ) Else If %couleur%==1 (Echo pantalon 6 2 1) Else Echo pantalon 6 2 2
```

---

If all you are doing is really just echoing those values, I'd offer the following modified script, *(without changing your screen layout)*.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:Menu
ClS
Set /A haut=pantalon=jupe=couleur=0
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle piece vestimentaire voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo -------
Echo Hommes
Echo -------
Echo Haut (1)
Echo(
Echo Haut (2)
Echo(
Echo Pantalon (3)
Echo(
Echo -------
Echo Femmes/Tous genres confondus
Echo -------
Echo Haut (4)
Echo(
Echo Jupe (5)
Echo(
Echo Pantalon (6)
Echo(
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 123456
Set "piece=%ERRORLEVEL%"
If %piece%==1 GoTo Haut
If %piece%==2 GoTo Haut
If %piece%==3 GoTo Pantalon
If %piece%==4 GoTo Haut
If %piece%==5 GoTo Jupe
If %piece%==6 GoTo Pantalon

:Haut
ClS
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle style d'haut voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Haut (1)
Echo(
Echo Haut (2)
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12
Set "haut=%ERRORLEVEL%"
GoTo Couleur

:Pantalon
ClS
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle style de pantalon voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Pantalon (1)
Echo(
Echo Pantalon (2)
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12
Set "pantalon=%ERRORLEVEL%"
GoTo Couleur

:Jupe
ClS
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle style de jupe voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Jupe (1)
Echo(
Echo Jupe (2)
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12
Set "jupe=%ERRORLEVEL%"
GoTo Couleur

:Couleur
ClS
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Quelle couleurs voulez-vous?
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo Rouge et noir (1)
Echo(
Echo Blue et noir (2)
Echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Echo(
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12
Set "couleur=%ERRORLEVEL%"

:Export
ClS
For %%G In (haut pantalon jupe) Do (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For %%H In (!%%G!) Do EndLocal & If %%H Gtr 0 Set "var=%%G" & Set "val=%%H")
Echo %var% %piece% %val% %couleur%
Pause 1> NUL
GoTo :Menu
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped make the project much better, but the issue still stands when I have used it. At the end, unless I remove the if statements that have %pantalon% or %jupe%, the program crashes once it reaches the end, rather than having echo display anything. Not sure if this is a problem on my end or not.

Comment: It crashes because of a syntax error when a variable is not defined (as I commented an hour ago). Depending on your answers, the program flow does not reach some labels, leaving the variables undefined. Either rebuild your logic (so *each* question has to be answered) or predefine your variables (all of them) like `set "pantalon=0"` etc.

Comment: Sorry @JackSamuel, I was otherwise engaged, and have now incorporated a method of ensuring each of your variables have predefined values for each loop, to prevent the issue mentioned twice now by Stephan. I have additionally added a potential modification for that `If` / `Else` section, because I dislike over parenthesising.

Comment: @Stephan Ah sorry I didn't notice your comment earlier, that's exactly what was the issue, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Compo No need to apologize, thank you so much for all your help. Not only did you find the solution to what I was trying to fix, but you vastly improved my program. Thank you for taking the time to help out!!

Answer (score 0):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:menu
FOR %%b IN (haut pantalon jupe couleur) DO SET /a %%b=0
CALL :accepter piece "piece vestimentaire" 123456 2 "Hommes" "Femmes/Tous genres confondus" 3 "Haut" "Haut" "Pantalon" 3 "Haut" "Jupe" "Pantalon"
GOTO piece%piece%


:haut
:Piece1
:Piece2
:Piece4
CALL :accepter haut "style d'haut" 12 0 2 "Haut" "Haut"
goto couleur

:pantalon
:piece3
:piece6
CALL :accepter pantalon "style de pantalon" 12 0 2 "Pantalon" "Pantalon"
goto couleur

:jupe
:piece5
CALL :accepter jupe "style de jupe" 12 0 2 "Jupe" "Jupe"
goto couleur

:couleur
CALL :accepter couleur "couleurs" 12 0 2 "Rouge et noir" "Blue et noir"

:export

cls
ECHO haut %haut% pantalon %pantalon% jupe %jupe% couleur %couleur%
pause>nul
goto menu

:: receive user input
:: %1 : receiving variable
:: %2 : Menu prompt
:: %3 : options list
:: %4 : number of groups
:: %5 : name of group (repeats %4 times)
:: %then : number of options within group
:: %followedby : Option name
:: %then, %followedby may be repeated

:accepter
cls
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: remove variables starting groupname
For %%b IN (groupname) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
SET "value=%1"
shift
SET "menuprompt=%~1"
shift
SET "options=%1"
SHIFT
SET "groups=%1"
SHIFT
SET /a groupcount=%groups%
SET /a groupindex=0
:getgroupname
IF %groupcount% neq 0 SET /a groupindex+=1&SET "groupname[!groupindex!]=%~1"&SHIFT&IF !groupindex! neq %groupcount% GOTO getgroupname

SET groupname

::
SET /a groupindex=0
SET /a option=0
SET "unusedoptions=%options%"
:: 
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo Quelle %menuprompt% voulez-vous?
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:: Display group
:displaygroup
SET /a groupindex+=1
IF DEFINED groupname[%groupindex%] (
 echo -------
 echo !groupname[%groupindex%]!
 echo -------
)
SET numoptionsingroup=%1&SHIFT

:showoption
IF %numoptionsingroup% gtr 0 (
 ECHO %~1 (!unusedoptions:~0,1!^)
 ECHO.
 SET "unusedoptions=!unusedoptions:~1!"
 SHIFT
 SET /a numoptionsingroup-=1
 GOTO showoption
)
IF DEFINED unusedoptions GOTO displaygroup 

echo.
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
echo.

choice /c %options% /M "%menuprompt%"
endlocal&SET %value%=%errorlevel%

GOTO :eof
```